# How to set HTML and CSS website on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, themes, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a Website that is designed on Html and Css. Now I want to make it same as on WordPress. Tell me the best possible options that help me to create same as its style. I also want to add that css on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your Admin Dashboard.

- You can use the WordPress Visual Editor to quickly add HTML files to
  your website.
- Click **Pages** in the left sidebar. Next, look at the left-hand
  sidebar.
- Choose an existing page or create a new one.
- Click **Add Block.**
- Add a **'File'** block.

Choose your HTML file.

Comment: what about gutenberg? Is their any link or something that help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for that.

1- Create your custom theme. this will allow you to add your HTML and CSS codes.
2- you can use page builders like Elementor and use the HTML element. then by adding your HTML and CSS codes that will render on the page.

Using both above methods will not allow you to edit page as you normally do using page builders. it has to be using HTML and CSS.

3- Re-create your website using page builders on wordpress, it will be easy and fast and you can make future edits easier.